# c++ understanding initialization list for C++ template class

Tags: c++, templates, initialization

I'm new to c++ templates. Could somebody explain the the code below specifically the line `struct c_graph`? Is this an initialization list for `c_graph`? Is it saying that the types `T_1` and `T_2` are of type `foo` of the template struct `test`?

```
template <class X>  
struct test
{
    using foo = X;
};

template <class T_1, class T_2>
struct c_graph : test<graph<T_1>>::foo, test<graph<T_2>>::foo 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no initialization list.

`c_graph` is derived from two classes.

```
struct c_graph : A, B
{
}
```

where

`A` is `test<graph<T_1>>::foo` and
`B` is `test<graph<T_2>>::foo`

Comment: @R Sahu thanks and may I ask why it specifies the type `::foo` and is not just `test<graph<T_1>>`?

Comment: @pleaseariane, the intention is to derive from `test<graph<T_1>>::foo`, not from `test<graph<T_1>>`.